# What is the Difference of of httpClient.request(request) and httpClient.post(..)

Tags: angular, httpresponse

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  formValues;

  constructor(private api:ApiService,private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmit(form:NgForm){
    this.formValues = form.value;

    //create new Object
    const x={
      username:this.formValues.username,
      password:this.formValues.password
    }
    console.log(x);
    //request server
    this.api.request('POST','',x).do((data)=>console.log(" server",data))
    .subscribe((data)=>console.log(" server",data.body));
    this.http.post('api/',x).subscribe((data)=>console.log(" this is http.post",data));
  }

}
```

api.service.ts

```
 @Injectable()
    export class ApiService {
      private baseUrl=environment.apiUrl;
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


      request(method:string,url:string,body?:Object):Observable<any> {

        url=`${this.baseUrl}/${url}`;

        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            // 'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
          })
        };

        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, body,httpOptions);
        return this.http.request(req);
      }

    }
```

server side

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
function apiRouter(){
    const router = express.Router();
    router.post('',(req,res)=>{
        console.log("api");
        let data= req.body
        console.log(data);
        res.status(200).json({data:"this is data"});
    }); 
    return router;
}
module.exports = apiRouter;
```

after run app and submit username and password I got following result.

```
{username: "a", password: "11"}password: "11"username: "a"__proto__: Object
main.b9ea608b60e7f19a98d0.bundle.js:1  server {type: 0}type: 0__proto__: Object
main.b9ea608b60e7f19a98d0.bundle.js:1  server undefined
main.b9ea608b60e7f19a98d0.bundle.js:1  server e {headers: t, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/", ok: true, …}
main.b9ea608b60e7f19a98d0.bundle.js:1  server {data: "this is data"}
main.b9ea608b60e7f19a98d0.bundle.js:1  this is http.post {data: "this is data"}
```

when I do httpClient.request() in the observable sequence has two event.
first one is {type: 0} and second one is e {headers: t, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/", ok: true, …}.
but in httpClient.post() has only {data: "this is data"}.

I have two question:
1. what is the difference of httpClient.request() and httpClient.post()
2. in httpClient.request() why there are is {type: 0} returned?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: In request you are free to send any request method, and post is just post

Comment: Is that a cross domain call ?
I am getting same kind of response.
I think its a CORS request the first time ,and the actual request call the second time.